# Can't connect to Azure sql server or even ping

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I can't connect to my Azure SQL Database that I have hosted on MS Azure.I have tried with Visual Studio and MSSM with no luck.

I can't seem to work out how I could possibly be going wrong. I allowed access to the server on all IPs.

I am using the correct login info.

I dont seem to be even able to ping the server, despite it showing no issues in the Azure interface.

The server is located at: kkbpeyaf0t.database.windows.net

Comment: Did you enable to access from _outside_ to your SQL Server? Also: What connection parameters do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to connect to the URL you provided using SSMS and it gave me a login failed (which I expected), so that tells me that the database is running and that you did indeed open up the IP ranges to allow anything (which isn't a best practice, but I'm assuming you did this as part of your troubleshooting). IF the Azure SQL DB firewall was still in the way it would block immediately indicating so.

I would think that if you have the correct username and password combination it should connect. Make sure that your outbound port 1433 isn't being blocked by your own firewall (machine, work, ISP, etc.).

Azure SQL Database won't respond to pings.

[Docs can be found on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336282.aspx).